# Ошибка unknown custom element: <temp-component> - did you register the component correctly? Vue js

Tags: vue.js

При импорте родительского компонента в дочерний появляется ошибка Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

Структура следующая:

```
    <temp-сomponent>
       <row-сomponent>
          <col-сomponent>
              тут импортируется родительский компонет (tempComponent) в 
              дочернем (colComponent)
          </col-сomponent>
       </row-сomponent>
    </temp-сomponent>
```

При такой иерархии появляется вышеупомянутая ошибка. В чем может быть дело?
    Импорт следующий:

```
    <template>
      <div class="col-block">
        <button @click="$emit('removeCol')">removeCol</button>
        <div>
           <temp-component></temp-component>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>

<script>
  import tempComponent from './tempComponent';
    export default {
    name: "colComponent",
    components: {tempComponent}
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Корневой `div` нужен

Comment: @doox911, да не, тут просто `name:` и `components:` неправильно записаны.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Стиль-именования](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) компонентов vue
2. [Рекурсивные-компоненты](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B)
3. Ваша структура не понятна. Вы регистрируете `tempComponent` внутри которого находится `rowComponent` и `colComponent`, а затем `tempComponent` же (родитель) вставляете внутрь `colComponent` (дочерний элемент).

**Предлагаю такую структуру:**

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-e9rdx?fontsize=14) --> Components

**TempComponent.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <temp-component>
      <row-component>
        <col-component>
          тут импортируется родительский компонет (tempComponent) в
          дочернем (colComponent)
        </col-component>
      </row-component>
    </temp-component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ColComponent from "./ColComponent";
import RowComponent from "./RowComponent";

export default {
  name: "TempComponent",
  components: {
    ColComponent,
    RowComponent
  }
};
</script>
```

**ColComponent.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div class="col-block">
    <button @click="$emit('removeCol')">removeCol</button>


    Col Component
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TempComponent from "./TempComponent";

export default {
  name: "ColComponent",
  components: {
    TempComponent
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: @РустамГимранов, спасибо)) добавила и в ответ ссылку

Answer (score 0):

Ответ нашелся, нужно сделать в дочернем компоненте col-component:

```
components: { temp-сomponent: () => import('./TempComponent.vue')}
```

После этого ошибка пропадает